# A sql statement can execute in mysql but cannot execute by using mybatis

Tags: mybatis

Here is my SQL statement:

```
<select id="selectRanking" parameterType="java.util.HashMap"
        resultMap="BaseResultMap">
        set @rownum=0;
        select @rownum=@rownum+1 as rank, s.userId as userId, s.stageId as stageId, s.encryptName as encryptName, s.lastModifyTime as lastModifyTime, s.friendNum as friendNum
        from T_Friend_Ranking s
        WHERE s.stageId=#{record.stageId,jdbcType=BIGINT} AND  s.friendNum!=0
        order by friendNum DESC ,lastModifyTime ASC limit #{record.rankingNum}
</select>
```

and the BaseResultMap:

```
<resultMap id="BaseResultMap" type="FriendRanking">
    <constructor>
        <idArg column="userId" javaType="java.lang.Long" jdbcType="BIGINT"/>
        <idArg column="stageId" javaType="java.lang.Long" jdbcType="BIGINT"/>
        <arg column="encryptName" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>
        <arg column="lastModifyTime" javaType="java.util.Date" jdbcType="TIMESTAMP"/>
        <arg column="friendNum" javaType="java.lang.Long" jdbcType="BIGINT"/>
        <arg column="rank" javaType="java.lang.Integer" jdbcType="INTEGER"/>
    </constructor>
</resultMap>
```

The exception is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near
>
> Error querying database.  Cause:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select s.userId
>   as userId, s.stageId as stageId, s.encryptName as encryptName, s' at
>   line 2
>       ### The error may exist in file [FriendRankingMapper.xml]### The error may involve com.***.FriendRankingMapper.selectRanking-Inline###
>   The error occurred while setting parameters### SQL: set @rowNum=0;
>   select s.userId as userId, s.stageId as stageId, s.encryptName as
>   encryptName, s.lastModifyTime as lastModifyTime, s.friendNum as
>   friendNum,         (@rowNum:=@rowNum+1) as rank         from
>   T_Friend_Ranking s         WHERE s.stageId=?         order by
>   friendNum DESC ,lastModifyTime ASC limit ? ###
>   Cause:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select
>   s.userId as userId, s.stageId as stageId, s.encryptName as
>   encryptName, s' at line 2 ; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select s.userId
>   as userId, s.stageId as stageId, s.encryptName as encryptName, s' at
>   line 2 at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)

I made a break point, copied the sql statement after prepare and ran it in mysql directly: there is no mistake and I can get the right result.
How can I resolve this?

Comment: Each MyBatis query can contain only one statement. In your query there are two statements: a "set" statement followed by a "select" statement.

Comment: O,I got it,Thank you very much~  I need query top #{record.rankingNum} students order by friendNum, and calculate the ranking by the way. Now I delete @ranknum, and delete "<arg column="rank" javaType="java.lang.Integer" jdbcType="INTEGER"/>" in BaseResultMap, and set ranking value after run sql in java code. However I still like to know the way to calculate ranking in sql directly rather than in java code. Maybe I can learn more knowledge. How can I achieve ? Thank you very much again~